# convert xml made by php to json

Tags: php, xml, json

I want to load remote xml file in php and convert that to Json.
first I used cUrl for fetch xml data :

xmlparse.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$url = 'http://www.example.com/xml.php';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIE,'Esperantus_Language_ime=en-US;Esperantus_Language_fa=en-US;PortalAlias=fa;refreshed=true;.ASPXAUTH=;portalrole=;');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_exec($curl);
```

when execute script xml show.

I used followed function for convert xml to json :

index.php

```
function Parse ($url) {
  $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);

  //$fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
  //$fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));

  $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
  $json = json_encode($simpleXml);

  return $json;
}
echo Parse('xmlparse.php');
```

but this not work and get error :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 8: parser error : ParsePI: PI php never end ... in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: curl_exec($curl); in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 8: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: curl_exec($curl); in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^ in D:\xampp\htdocs\xml\index.php on line 12
false
```

how can I load remote xml and convert to json.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Have you tried removing all the `str_replace()`s? They look unnecessary if the XML is valid

Comment: What is in those lines the parser complains about? What does the XML look like?

Comment: What does `$fileContents` look like before passing it to `simplexml_load_string`? Is it valid XML?

Comment: i want to load xmlparser.php.